# Coloring of merged $C_4$ and $C_5$ graph

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics

I'm learning Polya's enumeration theorem and Burnside lemma.
I found a task that considers graph $G = C_4 + C_5$ where $C_k$ is $k$-cycle and set of edges is defined like this: all old edges are in graph $G$ and every vertex from $C_4$ is connected to every vertex from $C_5$.

I need to find number of 3-colorings of graph $G$ such that 3 colors are red, 3 colors are green and 3 colors are blue.

If i could find index cycle of this graph then answer would simply be coefficient next to $a^3b^3c^3$, but i can't. I also tried to count number of fixed points under some actions, but i can't figure out how many actions are there, but to me it looks like a lot of actions gonna have 0 fixed point 3-3-3colorings, so answer mostly depends on how many actions there are.

Important: Graphs are considered the same under some automorphism of graph

I'd really appreciate some help on this